# Boost converter 100mV to 5V

Tags: integrated-circuit, transformer, boost

I am trying to design a boost converter which converts 100mV to 5V. 100mV is the minimum I get from my DC motor which I used as a generator and max is around 1V.

I tried searching for the IC's which does this but didn't find any. I found some IC's whose minimum operating voltage was around 500mV but I need 100mV. So I was thinking of using a DC transformer to amplify the 100mV. Is it possible to do this? Or is there already available IC's which does this?

Comment: Is the DC motor being used exclusively as a generator? Do you have an auxiliary supply that can be used to help boost the low voltage level? That supply doesn't need to provide much energy? How much current can your motor supply when it is generating 100mV? How much energy are you trying to store and how quickly do you want to store this energy?

Comment: Hello Andy yes I used a DC motor as a generator. I don't have any auxiliary power to help the boost converter. It generates around 20mA at 100mV and I get max of around 300-400mA.I am just trying to charge a single cell lithium ion battery with this.

Comment: Did you consider if your requirements are physically feasible? The energy conservation principle must hold (you cannot beat physics, no matter how hard you try). So at best your motor outputs 400mA@100mV. Assuming for simplicity they are dc values, your output power will be 40mW ***maximum***.

Comment: Likely you won't be able to reach high efficiency with a DIY solution, so probably 70% efficiency is really the best you can hope for, thus the output power will be around 28mW. Since you need 5V output, any converter won't be able to provide more than 5.6mA **max** (more or less). And note that these are generous figures. If those 5.6mA are not enough for you, then you are out of luck.

Answer (score 7):

Linear technology makes a few ICs that can boost extremely low voltages up to a usable level for energy harvesting purposes:

http://www.linear.com/product/LTC3108

Alternatively, you could roll your own solution. Such a low suply voltage will require using a JFET or a depletion mode MOSFET as the active element. I designed a self-resonant converter using a depletion mode MOSFET, a few transistors, and an ISDN/ADSL transformer a while back that I could make work down to 0.3 volts and might be able to go lower, but it would need some work.  There are also several patents which are out of protection online like this one:

https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/pdfs/US4734658.pdf

Which you could use as a starting point.

Comment: thank you Bitrex. I also did see the LTC3108 but the problem is that its output current is very low 9mA. I will be having like 300-400 mA at the max so I want to utilize all the energy its producing. Is there any alternative way?

Comment: @user2280164 What kind of motor are you using? A 1 volt maximum output seems low.  In any case, there are low voltage boost converters that can deliver that kind of current at max and start up at around 0.5 to 0.7 volts, but can run down to 0.3 volts or so. With one of those it shouldn't be too difficult to have a joule theif type circuit like the one in my second link that bootstraps the main boost converter, to get it running when the supply is below the main converters lockout voltage.

Comment: @user2280164 Going all the way down to 0.1 volts may be difficult..not saying that it couldn't be done, but it would probably require a more complicated switching arrangement where different supplies are switched in and out depending on the supply voltage. You may have to be willing to compromise your requirements somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

How much current do you require? If it is very low you might want to consider a Dickson charge pump. They are very easy to make. The output can be fed to a regulator.